# htaccess redirect link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried google, many tutorials but still have some problems with redirecting some links. Maybe my actual htaccess generates some conflicts?

Tried for example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kanaly_rss
RewriteRule rss\.php\?kat=(.*) /rss/$1 [R,L]
```

Any some others combinations.

I want to redirect links:
kanaly_rss/rss.php?kat=XXX

to

rss/XXX

My .htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # redirect old links
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !redirected_oldlink
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} co=
  RewriteRule (.*) /redirected_oldlink.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php/?\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php/?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these tow lines :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?kat=([^$]*)&?
RewriteRule ^kanaly_rss/rss.php /rss/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Another little edit and it works.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?kat=(.*)&?
RewriteRule ^kanaly_rss/rss.php /rss/%2? [L,R=301]

Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes my mistake (this does not support pcre) good ^^ you are welcome :)